# Solving String reduction Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode

I am preparing myself for an interview that I have on monday and I found this problem to resolve called "[String Reduction](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4eac48496bee2)". The problem is stated like this :

> Given a string consisting of a,b and c's, we can perform the following
>   operation: Take any two adjacent distinct characters and replace it
>   with the third character. For example, if 'a' and 'c' are adjacent,
>   they can replaced with 'b'. What is the smallest string which can
>   result by applying this operation repeatedly?
>
> For instance, cab -> cc or cab -> bb, resulting in a string of length
>   2. For this one, one optimal solution is: bcab -> aab -> ac -> b. No more operations can be applied and the resultant string has length 1.
>   If the string is = CCCCC, no operations can be performed and so the
>   answer is 5.

I have seen a lot [questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551519/string-reduction-programming-contest-solution-needed) on stackoverflow but I would like to verify my own algorithm. Here is my algorithm in pseudo code. In my code

1. S is my string to reduce
2. S[i] is the character at index i
3. P is a stack:
4. redux is the function that reduces the characters.

   ```
   function reduction(S[1..n]){        
   P = create_empty_stack();
   for i = 1 to n
   do
      car = S[i];
      while (notEmpty(P))
      do
         head = peek(p);
         if( head == car) break;
         else {
            popped = pop(P);
            car = redux (car, popped);
          }  
      done
      push(car)
   done
   return size(P)}
   ```

The worst-case of my algorithms is O(n) because all the operations on the stack P is on O(1). I tried this algorithm in the examples above, I get the expected answers. 
Let me execute my algo with this example " *abacbcaa*" :

```
i = 1 :
   car = S[i] = a, P = {∅}
   P is empty, P = P U {car} -> P = {a}

 i = 2 :
   car = S[i] = b, P = {a}
   P is not empty :
       head = a
       head != car ->
            popped = Pop(P) = a 
            car = reduction (car, popped) = reduction (a,b) = c
            P = {∅}

    push(car, P) -> P = {c}



i = 3 :
   car = S[i] = a, P = {c}
   P is not empty :
       head = c
       head != car ->
            popped = Pop(P) = c 
            car = reduction (car, popped) = reduction (a,c) = b
            P = {∅}

    push(car, P) -> P = {b}


 ...


 i = 5 : (interesting case)
  car = S[i] = c, P = {c}
   P is not empty :
       head = c
       head == car -> break

    push(car, P) -> P = {c, c}


 i = 6 :
  car = S[i] = b, P = {c, c}
   P is not empty :
       head = c
       head != car ->
            popped = Pop(P) = c 
            car = reduction (car, popped) = reduction (b,c) = a
            P = {c}

   P is not empty : // (note in this case car = a)
       head = c
       head != car ->
            popped = Pop(P) = c 
            car = reduction (car, popped) = reduction (a,c) = b
            P = {∅}
    push(car, P) -> P = {b}

... and it continues until n
```

I have run this algorithm on various examples like this, it seems to work. 
I have written a code in Java that test this algorithm, when I submit my code to the system, I am getting wrong answers. I have posted the java code on [gisthub](https://gist.github.com/2793850)  so you can see it.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my algorithm.

Comment: It is asking for the smallest string, then it means if there are more than one way to reduce the string, you have to find it. You seem to only search for the first way of reduction, of course, it will fail. Sometimes, not using a rule and wait for more characters to come may result in a better result.

Comment: @acattle yeap, but only in the first case, the first character. In every for-loop, the stack will have at least one character.

Comment: @nhahtdh can you be more specific??

Comment: I don't think it is possible to obtain a `O(n)` algorithm...

Comment: this simple algorithm might be useful http://jsfiddle.net/YFw4G/ JavaScript is easy to understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to try to explain what `nhahtdh` means. There are multiple reasons why your algorithm fails. But the most fundamental one is that at each point in time, only the first character observed has a chance to be pushed on the stack `p`. It should not be this way, as you can start a reduction basically from any position.

Let me give you the string  `abcc`. If I breakpoint at

```
car = S[i];
```

The algo run as :

```
p = {∅}, s = _abcc //underscore is the position
p = {a}, s = a_bcc  
p = {c}, s = ab_cc
```

At this point you are stuck with a reduction `ccc`

But there is another reduction : `abcc -> aac ->ab ->c`

Besides, returning the size of the stack `P` is wrong. `cc` cannot be reduced, but
the algorithm will return `1`. You should also count the number of times you skip.

Comment: No. You need to cover ALL cases. Naively for a given string of size `n` there are `n-1` redux leading to `n-1` strings of size `n-1`. this lead to a n! complexity, which is catastrophic. There must be a way (dyn. programming, etc...) to reduce this complexity.

Answer (score 0):

you can also solve this question using brute force...and recursion

```
for all n-1 pairs(2 char) replace it with 3rd char if possible and apply reduce on this new string of length n-1
    for all n-2 pairs replace it with 3rd char and apply reduce on new string
         for all n-3 pairs....and so on
```

The new string of length n-1 will have n-2 pairs and similarly new string of length n-2 will have n-3 pairs.

while applying this approach keep storing the minimum value

```
if (new_min < min)
    min = new_min
```

Implementation: http://justprogrammng.blogspot.com/2012/06/interviewstreet-challenge-string.html